# Como puedo guardar un registro en una base de datos, cuando una variable de tipo bool cambie a True y lo haga una sola vez en C#?

Tags: c#

Quiero guardar registros en una base de datos Mysql  con C#, y quiero que se guarden cuando una variable de tipo bool cambie a True, esta variable sera enviada desde un PLC siemens , y que el registro lo mande una sola vez, actualmente lo realizo con un boton , Gracias

```
private void btnGuardar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Clases.CTest objetoTest = new Clases.CTest();
        objetoTest.GuardarTest(txt1, txt2, txt3, txt4, txt5, txt6, txt7, txt8, txt9, txt10, txt11);
        objetoTest.MostartTest(dgvTotalTest);
    }
```

Comment: Si la variable es enviada desde un PLC, cómo lo recibes del lado de C#? Cómo se conecta el PLC con el server? Quién está esperando a que el PLC envíe esa variable? Tal vez un poco investigación sea necesaria: el sitio oficial de siemes [tiene información que puedes usar](https://support.industry.siemens.com/forum/WW/en/posts/c-application-to-make-connection-and-read-write-from-plc/180841)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que tu tienes es uno de los casos de usos más importantes para las propiedades, que es poder realizar una acción cuando la seteas y/o cuando obtienes su valor.

Tienes que tener algo así:

```
private bool _variable = false;
public bool variable
{
    get
    {
        return _variable;
    }
    set
    {
        _variable = value;
        if (_variable) //Cuando la "variable" es true llama a la función Guardar
        {
            Guardar();
        }
    }
}
private void Guardar()
{
    Clases.CTest objetoTest = new Clases.CTest();
    objetoTest.GuardarTest(txt1, txt2, txt3, txt4, txt5, txt6, txt7, txt8, txt9, txt10, txt11);
    objetoTest.MostartTest(dgvTotalTest);
}
```